# Can I use my wifi wingle to route and share LAN internet over wifi instead of its built in cellular network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, hotspot

I have a [wingle EC 315](http://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/mobile-broadband/ec315-en.htm) which can create a wi-fi hot-spot but I **DON'T** want its evdo 3g network to be shared over wifi but want to share my LAN internet through it.

I came across many sites but each one is providing details how to share its cellular network over LAN but I need just opposite of it.(I don't want to use its cellular network just want to use this device as a router.)
Will anyone please guide me if it is possible or not and if yes then how?

Comment: If the dongle can be configured to share wifi, yes. Look at the documentation of the device, or at least link to it - I have no idea what EC315 is.

Comment: Thanks for your concern.EC 315 is a Huawei  branded wifi evdo dongle named as tata photon max wi fi data card.

Comment: Apparently it's a "wingle" not a "dongle" - whatever that means. [With tech specs](http://consumer.huawei.com/en/mobile-broadband/wingles/tech-specs/ec315-en.htm) that don't say and [no documentation](http://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/mobile-broadband/ec315-en.htm). I *think* the tech spec of communication system would indicate it can only stream out wifi, and in cellular. You could attempt to plug a LAN cable into the computer and share the network with the wingle, *but the wingle might comingle the signals*.

Comment: Oh yes this one is a wingle but I don't have much information regarding this.please help me out.

Comment: I have done that already. But I'm unable to get through it.

Comment: Then I would say no - just get a router for the LAN to make it a WAN.

Comment: you know My LAN internet is configured with dynamic IP and I have a dialup connection for it which connects to my ISP using PPPoE and I have shared this dial up with the adapter shown by my device. the device is accessible in browser only using its static DHCP IP but adapter for it is showing an IPv4 address which is generated by its DHCP mechanism for example if device is accessed by IP 192.168.137.2 then its adapter shows IPv4 address as 192.168.137.3 and because it is shared with my dial up its default gateway becomes 192.168.137.1.

Comment: I agree with @Raystafarian the wingle EC 315 may not mingle too well with Lan. Getting a router would suit your needs well and if you are on a budget there are plenty of options out there.

Comment: device is still working as a hotspot and I can connect my other wi fi enabled devices to communicate with each other so I thought that it would be great if it could be linked with my dialup so as all devices connected to this hotspot may use Internet.

Comment: Any way I thank all of you for taking this issue in concern. It was a random idea .....and could be a matter of joy for everyone if it could be possible...:-)thank you once again